# How to write path of partition

Tags: linux, linux-mint, partition, hard-disk

I'm new to Linux and I'm trying to create a file system for a new partition but I need to find out how to write the path to it first. The storage disk I'm using is /dev/sdb in specific since sda has my operating system. It's probably an simple answer but I can't wrap my head around it.[image]

Comment: https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/arm64/apcs04.html.en

https://oracle-base.com/articles/linux/linux-disk-partitioning

https://tec4tric.com/linux/dev-sda-in-linux

`/dev/sdb` represents the entire disk, `/dev/sdb1`, `/dev/sdb2`, `/dev/sdb3`, etc represent individual partitions.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thank you so much

Comment: I would strongly urge you to use `gparted` instead of `parted` so you can get a more user-friendly graphical interface.